# Is a range of numbers 'extended' to a higher upper limit, or is it 'expanded' to a higher upper limit?

Tags: grammar

For example, is the range of numbers from 1–3 extended to 1–7, or is it expanded to 1–7?

Answer (score 2):

**Expand** is generally used when we talk about volume. On the other hand, **extend** is used with respect to the reach or length. For example:

> The reach of the shot is **extended** from 3 meters to 7 meters.
>
> The volume of the gas **expanded** from 3 meter-cube to 7 meter-cube.
>
> After the magic spell my hand **extended** from 2 meters to 3 meters, or grew by 1 meter.

Answer (score -1):

*Expanded* is the term you would use. *Expanding* is a mathematical term, though it has a different meaning than the one you are using it for.

[*To extend*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extend?s=t) can mean to expand, but usually means to stretch, as you would extend your arm, or a telescope.

[*To expand*](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/expand?s=t) usually means to add on to, as you would expand your knowledge, or a book. This is what you are doing to your set of numbers.